# Nested custom element not rendered when parent element is instantiated programmatically

Tags: javascript, rendering, custom-element

For a Single Page Application I have registered some custom elements to the `customElementRegistry` which are rendered from string literals via `insertAdjacentHTML()`. Nesting these elements is no problem when done in html. But when I try to instantiate a parent custom element programmatically starting from `customElements.get('entry-page')` or `document.createElement('div', {is: 'entry-page'})`, the nested custom elements do not render as if not defined at all. Even `customElements.whenDefined('nested-element').then(...)` doesn't help.

```js
function registerCustomElement(name, tpl) {
  class cls extends HTMLDivElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', tpl)
    }
  };
  customElements.define(name, cls, {
    extends: 'div'
  })
}
let tpl1 = '<p class="box">inner HTML</p>'
let tpl2 = '<article class="outer">outer HTML<inner-html></inner-html></article>'
let tpl3 = '<article class="outer">revised outer HTML<div is="inner-html"></div></article>'

registerCustomElement('inner-html', tpl1)
registerCustomElement('outer-html', tpl2)
registerCustomElement('outer-html-revised', tpl3)
document.querySelector('main')
  .insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div is="outer-html"></div>')
document.querySelector('main')
  .insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div is="outer-html-revised"></div>')
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'sans serif';
  font-size: 0.8em
}

.box {
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: olive;
}

.outer {
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  border: 2px solid darkorange
}
```

```html
<h1>Embedded in html</h1>
<h2>version with 'inner-html' element</h2>
<outer-html></outer-html>
<h2>version with 'div is inner-html' element</h2>
<outer-html-revised></outer-html-revised>
<h1>Embedded programmatically</h1>
<main></main>
```

Each element is defined separately as a ES6 Module. I am currently not using shadow DOM.

Why a custom element does fully render including all nested elements when embedded in HTML, but not when implemented in the DOM programmatically?

**Edit** As Danny Engelman stated, the only cross-browser option is to extend `HTMLElement`.

Comment: with ``extends HTMLDivElement``, you are on a dead end track. Apple has, since 2016, stated they will never implement these _Customized Built-In Elements_. So ``extends HTMLElement`` (_Autonomous Elements_) is the only cross browser option.

Answer (score 0):

While in HTML the custom elements may be referenced by there names even in the string literals, the custom elements are based upon, this seems not to be true, when they are generated programmatically. In this case the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#attr-is-during-serialization) requires something like `<div is="custom-element-name">`, but it wouldn't be cross-browser, as Apple only supports `HTMLElement`.

Comment: Be aware that the "is" attribute is not supported by WebKit (i.e.: Safari) (https://caniuse.com/custom-elementsv1 and https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=182671 )